# md-radio-button inside md-list-item

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material2

I try to resolve this issue :

https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/1518

I'd like to click anywhere on the line of my md-item and it should trigger the action of the radio-button.

---

settings.component.html :

```
<md-radio-group [(ngModel)]="lang">
  <md-list-item (click)="changeLanguageTo(l)" *ngFor="let l of langOptions">
    <md-radio-button [value]="l">
       {{l}}
    </md-radio-button>
  </md-list-item>
</md-radio-group>
<p>Your have selected : {{lang}}</p>
```

---

settings.component.ts :

```
private langOptions = [
  'fr',
  'en'
];
private lang: string = 'en';
changeLanguageTo(lang) {
  this.lang = lang || this.lang;
  console.log(this.lang);
  this.translate.use(this.lang);
}
```

By default, in my app.components.ts file, my current lang which is selected is English.

Actually, the event for change lang works fine but I didn't understand why I don't have a lang selected by default on the radio button ?

Why the ngModel doesn't init the current lang which is set by default ?
Any ideas ?

Comment: ... the action of the radio-button (sorry) not checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I founded the solution :

```
      <md-radio-group [(ngModel)]="lang">
        <md-list-item (click)="changeLanguageTo(l)" *ngFor="let l of langOptions">
          <md-radio-button [value]="l" [checked]="lang == l">
            {{l}}
          </md-radio-button>
        </md-list-item>
      </md-radio-group>

      <p>Your have selected : {{lang}}</p>
```